# Running multiple Junit test cases for camel routes

Tags: grails, testing, junit, apache-camel, integration-testing

I am doing Junit integration testing for testing my camel routes, I have 2 tests methods in a Test class.

when both methods run independently, they executes and Test passed successfully.

But if i run entire class containing both test cases, it hangs on saying running

```
|Running 2 integration tests... 1 of 2
|Running 2 integration tests... 2 of 2
```

it didn't move forward, neither pass nor fails.

I have put @DirtiesContext on both test cases too, but no luck.

I don't know what am doing wrong.

Has anyone has any idea on this, please share your view.

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: hi @vikingsteve can you share your email, can't share the code publically.

Comment: Don't know the exact issue but i solved the issue by putting both testcases in separate class & it worked fine now.

Comment: Great! Likely related to any `@Before` or `@BeforeClass` "state", or state due to DI, or lastly perhaps any static code. Glad you solved it.